# Display users in order by an "order" custom meta field

Tags: users, user-meta

Alright, so here's my current code (which works, displaying the users in order by ID and excluding the admin user):

```
$site_admin = "1";
$order = 'ID';
$user_ids = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE ID != '$site_admin' ORDER BY $order"); // query users
foreach($user_ids as $user_id) : // start authors' profile "loop"
    $user = get_userdata($user_id);

    $level = $user->user_level;
    if ($level > 0) 
    { ?>

    ((information to display goes here))

   <?php  } ?>
```

What I'd like to do is add a meta field (I believe that's the right terminology, but please correct if wrong), and I have already added that, then type in a number for each author.

Here's how that was added (in functions.php):

```
<?php function my_new_contactmethods( $contactmethods ) {
$contactmethods['order'] = 'Order on the About Page'; 
return $contactmethods;
}
add_filter('user_contactmethods','my_new_contactmethods',10,1);?>
```

Last, I'd like to display the users in that order.

There are a number of related questions, but none that I could find that order the users by fields which are added in addition to the typical Wordpress user information (e.g. ID, user_nicename, etc.) I can simply replace "ID" in the code above with "user_nicename" and that works fine, but I need to be able to manually set the order of each of the users, so none of the built-in fields will work for that purpose.

Comment: Is this question about adding a field to the user profile, or listing users by that field? Note that we have a 1 question per question policy

Answer (score 1):

You can use the default function [get_users()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users), and then re order the result by the meta id. Here is the [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30302/order-users-by-custom-user-meta)

Comment: Well, I'm already ordering them by ID; I'm hoping to order them by something else – however, I might be able to adapt something here, so thanks!